# Easing String not working properly for me. Can someone describe what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me w/ this code snippet. I'm animating a block of content and my easing string isn't working correct for me. Can someone quickly point out what I've done wrong? Thanks

```
  // JavaScript Document
    $(document).ready(function() {            

            $('.learnmore').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().delay(100).animate({
                    top: '50px',
                    duration:400,
                    easing:'easeOutElastic'
                 })
            });
```

Comment: You're missing `});` for `$('.learnmore')`

Comment: I forgot to include that in the snippet above.. it is still not easing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `.animate` wrong. The two styles are :

`.animate([CSS Properties], [Options (Easing/Duration/Complete)])`

or

`.animate([CSS Properties], [Duration], [Easing], [Complete]);`

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You want this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().delay(100).animate({
    top: '50px'
}, {
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic'
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert! So to have a better understanding. I need to wrap my css properties inside their own curly brackets and declare the animation process in their curly brackets, correct?

Comment: @SirB: Yeah, it will accept two styles, argument one being an object containing the css properties, then a second object with the duration easing and complete values or a css properties object and individual arguments for the duration, then easing, then complete.

Comment: for anyone else with easing issues...a mix of jquery 2.1.1 and jquery-ui 1.11.3 allows the 1st signature to work but the 2nd did not, complained about easing not defined

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery library only has the easing modes `swing` and `linear`. You need the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) that includes the plugin.

Comment: I called the easing library however it is still not working.. is my syntax correct? I'm not a jQuery ninja.. so any advice or suggestions would be extremely helpful

Comment: @SirB: Then the easing exists at least, which makes it easier to use... Robert sorted the usage problem also.

Comment: @downvoter: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong with the answer, it can't improve it.

Comment: i upvoted this. not sure why you got downvoted - you were just trying to help